# PayPal Advanced Payflow

Tags: paypal

i am trying to integrate PayPal Payments Advanced..but it returns with error..: 
" Invalid merchant information: 10501-This transaction cannot be processed due to an invalid merchant configuration." 
What could be the solution..?

Answer (score 1):

Error code 10501 means that PayPal Payments Pro or PayPal Payments Advanced isn't active on your PayPal account.  You need to contact PayPal to get this resolved.